# How to disable headphone volume notifications - now that the option seems to have been removed

Tags: music, sound-volume, alert

I use my iPhone to play music in my car through Bluetooth. I use the car's volume control to control the actual volume.

However, to avoid distortion issues, when doing this I keep my iPhone's volume at maximum. This does NOT mean that I am actually listening too loudly. In fact, I could likely be listening to whisper-quiet music. However, iOS still detects this as "too loud" and occasionally gives me a "volume too loud" warning.

I want to disable this.

Online, I have found answers stating that in Settings you can [disable this](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/108968). However, it seems that on my own iOS version (17.3.1) - that option is not present.

Does anyone know if there's a workaround?

Comment: Probably this not about iOS version but (as stated in linked documentation): Due to regulations and safety standards, headphone notifications can't be turned off in certain countries or regions.